# Are sets that contain just integers ordered?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I wrote this code:

```
s = set(range(10))
print(s)
```

but every time the result is `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}`.
aren't sets unordered?
The set in this code is always ordered but not indexed.

Comment: They're _arbitrarily_ ordered data structures. You shouldn't write code that _relies_ on the order, but that doesn't mean that a given implementation won't retain e.g. insertion order.

Comment: Unordered does not mean randomly shuffled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, usually not.

```
>>> s = {8, 4, 0}
>>> print(s)
{8, 0, 4}
```

With `set(range(n))`, in current CPython, they're sorted because every number `i` gets placed at index `i` in the hash table. Because for example with n=20, the hash table gets 32 rows and number `i` gets mapped to `hash(i) % 32` = `i % 32` = `i`. So when that table is iterated, you get the numbers sorted. But it's an implementation detail, so **don't rely on it.**

Better demonstration, btw, also showing that it's not ordered in "insertion order" or so, but really gets sorted:

```
>>> from random import shuffle
>>> a = list(range(20))
>>> shuffle(a)
>>> a
[14, 15, 5, 17, 3, 18, 16, 7, 8, 19, 2, 10, 12, 6, 1, 9, 11, 4, 0, 13]
>>> set(a)
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19}
```

With my above `{8, 4, 0}`, the hash table has 8 rows and so `8` gets mapped to `hash(8) % 8` = `8 % 8` = `0` and thus gets put into row 0. Then `4` gets put into row 4. Then `0` *ought* to go into row 0, but since that's already occupied, it must go somewhere else and apparently ends up between the numbers `8` and `4`, i.e., in one of the rows 1, 2 or 3.

Visually:

```
Initial   After     After     After
empty     placing   placing   placing
table:    the 8:    the 4:    the 0:

0:        0: 8      0: 8      0: 8       
1:        1:        1:        1: 0  (or could be at place 2 or 3)       
2:        2:        2:        2:  
3:        3:        3:        3:  
4:        4:        4: 4      4: 4       
5:        5:        5:        5:        
6:        6:        6:        6:        
7:        7:        7:        7:
```